# Date difference in months issue

Tags: c#

This code lets you calulate the difference in months between two dates, Date2 > Date1

```
public int MonthDiff(DateTime Date1, DateTime Date2)
{
    return Math.Abs((Date2.Month - Date1.Month) + 12 * (Date2.Year - Date1.Year));
}
```

In my example if I put Date1 = "01/01/2019" & Date2 = "31/12/2019", it will return 11, and this is wrong, it should be 12. 

Also if I put Date1 = "25/01/2019" & Date = "31/12/2019", it should be 12.


So the question should I need to calculate by Days or what?

 I used this code

```
return Math.Abs(((Date2- Date1).Days / 30) + 12 * (Date2.Year - Date1.Year));
```

With Date1 = "01/01/2019" & Date2 = "31/12/2020", it shows 36 Months.

Comment: 12-1 is 11 and 12*0 is 0

Comment: "it will return 11, and this is wrong" - how is 12-1=11 wrong? Date.Month returns int <1,12>. Here, check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.month?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Apart from the fact that it's not wrong, I would avoid calculating differences in months due to the fact that months have different lengths, so when you say "three months", you don't actually know how many days that represents.

Comment: Looks like an off-by-1 error. Does `Math.Abs((Date2.Month - Date1.Month + 1) + 12 * (Date2.Year - Date1.Year))` do what you want?

Comment: What do you expect for the input 2019-01-01 and 2019-12-01? 12 months or 11 months?

Comment: And this is why SQL server counts the number of intervals that pass between two dates - asking for the `DATEDIFF(year, '1999-12-31 23:59:59', '2000-01-01 00:00:01')` reports 1 year between those dates even though it's actually only 2 seconds, which is a heck of a lot shorter than a year.. you'll have to accept the limitations/outliers with this (you're asking us a question we can't answer because we don't know your rules - are you rounding up?)

Comment: @Sweeper yes that help, I will test it, but I don't know if I will face an issue later, it should show 12 not 11,

Comment: @CaiusJard you are right, it justa matter of control

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know the difference between two dates in variable length units like months or years, you should use the built in timespan functionality rather than roll your own, and accept some compromises/approximations. The average number of days in a year is 365.2425. The average number of days in a month is 30.42 for a non leap year or 30.50 for a leap year, or 30.44 overall. Choose one of these values when approximating the months. Choose whether to round down, or round up, and to how many decimal places when working out the months/years

For example:

```
var a = DateTime.Now;
var b = DateTime.Now.AddDays(366);
var years = Math.Round((b-a).TotalDays/365.2425);
```

You could take some alternative approaches like:

- have an array of integers that depict the number of days in each month (over a four year period so leap February are accounted for) and a logic of "I will get the number of days between the two dates, then I will consider the month of the start date and set an array indexer variable pointing to that month in the a"rray-of-month-lengths", and I will subtract the number of days in that month from my total, then I'll move on to the next index in the array (going back to the array start if necessary) and subtract that.. and I'll keep doing it until the remaining total days is lower than the number of days in whatever month I'm looking at.. and the number of times I looped shall be the result of the number of months between the day"
- write a loop that adds one day to the start date until the end date is breached, and count how many times the current month number is different to the month number on the last iteration of the loop
- etc

These are decisions to implement very specific sorts of approximations

I don't think there is a good fact based answer to your question until you accurately explain every rule you want your math you work to, so all the exceptions can be coded for. Saying "x - y is 11 months and this is wrong" is not a rule; you need to say why it is wrong